# Displaying a certain image based on a pattern in an .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a series of images that I would like to rename for SEO purposes. However, I have over 6,000 images so I thought that there must be an easy rewrite for my .htaccess file.

The current images are currently named using the following pattern:

http://www.mydomain.com/images/small/00005712.jpg

http://www.mydomain.com/images/medium/00005712.jpg

http://www.mydomain.com/images/large/00005712.jpg

I would like to be able to call them with a naming scheme such as:

http://www.mydomain.com/5712s-keyword-phrase.jpg

http://www.mydomain.com/5712m-keyword-phrase.jpg

http://www.mydomain.com/5712l-keyword-phrase.jpg

This will allow me to change the display from:

```
<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/images/large/00005712.jpg" />
```

to

```
<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/5712l-keyword-phrase.jpg" />
```

The rewrite would hopefully allow me to simply change the pattern on the img src attribute in my php file. The img src attributes across the entire site with the new name would actually present the original images to the screen.

All of the filenames have 8 digit numeric names padded with 0's on the left.

Also note that if you know of a way to do this with the keyword-phrase on the left and the number being at the end, such like http://www.mydomain.com/keyword-phrase-5712s.jpg that it would be even better.

If I've not provided enough details, please let me know what I can do to clarify. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rewrite won't change any URLs that you have hardcoded in to your code (whether it be HTML pages or css `url()`). It would probably be best just to rename all of the images.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the fact that I can re-hardcode the src attribute of all 6,000+ images in one file because it is powered by php using a database to organize them. All I have to do is change the pattern on 1 line of code and all will point to the new naming pattern.

Comment: Can't you use that same PHP system to rename the images and run it on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename your folders to s m and l you can use 1 ruleset

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^0*([1-9])(\d*)(s|m|l)(.*)$ /images/$3/$1$2.jpg
```

otherwise you need 3

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^0*([1-9])(\d*)s(.*)$ /images/small/$1$2.jpg

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^0*([1-9])(\d*)m(.*)$ /images/medium/$1$2.jpg

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^0*([1-9])(\d*)l(.*)$ /images/large/$1$2.jpg
```

***Edit***

per comment below, to throw away SEO terms preceding the file name, use:

```
RewriteRule ^.*(\d+)s\.(jpg|gif|png)$ /images/small/$1.$2
RewriteRule ^.*(\d+)m\.(jpg|gif|png)$ /images/medium/$1.$2
RewriteRule ^.*(\d+)l\.(jpg|gif|png)$ /images/large/$1.$2
```

the .* at the beginning throws away any leading characters before the image digits. Since the leading zeros are included in the file url now, we can just use (\d+) to match 1 or more digits immediately preceding the (s|m|l) folder indicator and the image file extension.

Comment: `^0*([1-9])(\d*)l(.*)$` says to match any number of 0's, one number `1-9`, then any number of numbers.  The requested URL doesn't have leading 0's

Comment: that is true, it would have add leading zeros to the target file to pad it up to 8 digits. Not sure you can do that in regex, I dont think there's any strlen or number formatting options

Comment: the whole thing is a giant waste of time really (like many SEO practices). Even if Google does associate dynamically generated keywords with the images, its got to see the images as duplicate content for other keywords. If duplicate images are anything like duplicate pages, the 2nd-nth variations will be ignored and might even cause a penalty if they thought you were trying to game the system somehow...

Comment: You can shrink yours to `^(\d*)l(.*)$` and then use `$1` instead of `$1$2`.

Comment: This solution seems to work...almost...let me explain.

If I navigate my web browser to http://www.mydomain.com/00005712l.jpg it displays the correct image. As soon as I add anything in front of the zeroes, it ceases to display and returns a 404 error. Here is the code that I'm using:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)\.jpg$
RewriteRule (.*)(\d*)l(.*)$ /images/full/$2.jpg

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure mod rewrite is installed, and enabled on your server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule *(\d{8})l\.(gif|jpg|png)$ /images/large/$1.jpg
RewriteRule *(\d{8})s\.(gif|jpg|png)$ /images/small/$1.jpg
RewriteRule *(\d{8})m\.(gif|jpg|png)$ /images/medium/$1.jpg
```

Untested and I'll throw a few edits in to get it so.

`*` - Match any leading characters in the URL

`(\d{8})` - match a group of 8 digits

`l` - match for `large`

`\.` - Match a literal `.`

`(gif|jpg|png)` - Match `gif` or `jpg` or `png`

`$` - Match end of the URL

Put it all together:

Match any request of the form (which was your requested "better" solution)

`http://www.mydomain.com/keyword-phrase-{ANY 8 DIGITS}.gif`

`http://www.mydomain.com/keyword-phrase-{ANY 8 DIGITS}.jpg`

`http://www.mydomain.com/keyword-phrase-{ANY 8 DIGITS}.png`

Note

Mine is missing filling in padded leading 0's so you'd have to include the empty 0's in front.

Comment: that wont drop leading zeros though... needs to be like (0*)([1-9])(\d*) -> drop $1 use $2$3

Comment: Good call, I thought he wanted to keep the leading 0's.  Why the 3 digit matching groups through?

Comment: yeah i just realized the first matching group was unnecessary after posting that 0*([1-9])(\d*) -> use $1$2 would be the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symbolic link in server that will rewrite to your original path.

For your reference [link](http://www.php2s.com/linux/find-real-path-of-linux-symbolic-link-or-soft-link-files-%E2%80%93-linux-command-line.html)