Add text to image path when image has unique id in htaccess
I have a multilingual website. This website has over 10.000 images in different articles and growing.
I need to be able - if possible - to random rename the images as long as the unique image-id is also displayed in the end.
Lets take this image for example: gallery_964/15471298.webp
I would like to be able to use the image like this
<img src="gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp" /> //english
<img src="gallery_964/elefante-verde-15471298.webp" /> //portugese
<img src="gallery_964/grøn-elefant-15471298.webp" /> //danish

I have tried the following which did not work
RewriteRule ^.*(\d+)gallery_964\.(jpg|gif|png|webp)$ /gallery_964/$1.$2

I really can't figure it out at this point. Is it even possible?
EDIT
As per request - this is my full rewrite setup at the moment.
Header add "Cache-Control" "no-cache"
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://example.com$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule sitemap\.xml sitemap.php

RewriteRule ^gallery_964/.+(\d{8}).webp /gallery_964/$1.webp [L]

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/ld+json" \
                                  "application/manifest+json" \
                                  "application/rdf+xml" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/schema+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                  "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                  "application/x-javascript" \
                                  "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "font/eot" \
                                  "font/opentype" \
                                  "image/bmp" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                  "image/x-icon" \
                                  "text/cache-manifest" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/vcard" \
                                  "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                  "text/vtt" \
                                  "text/x-component" \
                                  "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                  "text/xml"
                                 
# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html###

</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 20000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"

</ifModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpeg|jpg|png|gif|swf|webp)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

EDIT 2
This is the error log
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2370e64f3f8][rid#237113e56e0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp -> gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2370e64f3f8][rid#237113e56e0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/] applying pattern '^(.*)\\/(\\?.*)?$' to uri 'gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp'
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2370e64f3f8][rid#237113e56e0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp -> gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2370e64f3f8][rid#237113e56e0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/] applying pattern 'sitemap\\.xml' to uri 'gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp'
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2370e64f3f8][rid#237113e56e0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp -> gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2370e64f3f8][rid#237113e56e0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/] applying pattern '^/gallery_964/.+(\\d{8}).webp' to uri 'gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp'
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2370e64f3f8][rid#237113e56e0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp -> gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2370e64f3f8][rid#237113e56e0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/] applying pattern '^404$' to uri 'gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp'
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] 127.0.0.1 - - [127.0.0.1/sid#2370e64f3f8][rid#237113e56e0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/] pass through C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.356620 2024] [core:info] [pid 21984:tid 1924] [client 127.0.0.1:59035] AH00128: File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.518984 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1/multi/gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp
[Fri Oct 25 13:52:04.518984 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 21984:tid 1924] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 127.0.0.1:59035] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://127.0.0.1/multi/gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp


Your regular expression is invalid, it can not start with a quantifier.

@C3roe - I see! I will look into this - thank you. I have studied this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753095 - where this was one of the suggestions.

(\d{8})l - and what's with the l there, there is no l after the digits in your given example URLs.

You're right! I was a little fast there. I accidentally posted the wrong line. Thank you.

RewriteRule ^gallery_964/.*(\d{8}).webp /gallery_964/$1.webp should do the job, if you don't need the gallery_964 folder part to be dynamic. https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=c11e15ec-06ea-4354-ad29-83420f251e4b

@C3roe - Thank you. It does unfortunately not seem to work. The folder does not need to change. When using this code i just get "The requested URL was not found on this server.". Even the correct url shows "not found". So even gallery_964/15471298.webp can't be found - even though this 100% exist.

Ah, yes, gallery_964/15471298.webp would match the pattern again, because .* allows for nothing in that place. Try and change that part to .+, to demand at least one character before the digits.

Okay - so RewriteRule ^gallery_964/.+(\d{8}).webp /gallery_964/$1.webp can now show the original image called gallery_964/15471298.webp - but it won't show up if i put anything in front of it like gallery_964/green-elephant-15471298.webp I really appreciate your help!

Try adding the [L] flag at the end, so that following rules (if any) can't influence the result any further. If that doesn't help, then please show your full rewrite setup.

@C3roe - I just edited the post so it contains my whole htaccess at the moment. It's not much, because I'm in the process of redesigning my website and optimize the process of adding content. Here it would be very efficient for me to be able to use the same image with different descriptions for different languages. Thank you yet again! As for testing I'm simply testing only 1 image called gallery_964/15471298.web

That should still work, according to https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=f5e6c8f2-420a-4699-8f52-c618f04cd85e And it doesn't look like the resulting URL, when send through the process again, gets rewritten to anything else. (Although, this testing tool isn't perfect, and can produce inaccurate results, especially when it relates to anything it doesn't support or variable values it doesn't know.) [...]

[...] Not sure what exactly is going on; when in doubt, it is always a good idea to enable some rewrite logging, then you can retrace what actually happens, in detail. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

@C3roe - Thank you again. I have now tried to activate the error log. I have posted the log in the post. Can you see anything wrong with it?

internal redirect with /gallery_964/15471298.webp [INTERNAL REDIRECT] - so the internal redirect appears to have worked as intended; but then there is File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/gallery_964/15471298.webp Is that supposed to be the physical location of the file?

@C3roe - No that is not the place the file is supposed to be. It should be here: C:/xampp/htdocs/multi/gallery_964/15471298.webp - so I tried adding / like this RewriteRule ^/gallery_964/.+(\d{8}).webp /gallery_964/$1.webp [L] - it does not work - the error log is completely different though. I have updated it.

No, RewriteRule ^/... will never match, when configured in .htaccess - the path to the current directory that the .htaccess is in, has already been stripped off, so what the RewriteRule matches against, never starts with a slash. Plus, the problem wasn't with the originally requested URL with your additional text in it, but with the substitution URL. If anything, the prefix would need adding to the substitution URL, /multi/gallery_964/$1.webp - but that can't really be the "clean" solution here.

I'm guessing the issue has something to do with how you set up your virtual host / how you are reaching the project in your browser.

@C3roe - Okay, thank you. I will try to upload the files to my actual webhost to see if it works - I will return.

@C3roe - So I uploaded the version to my webhost in a subfolder. That didn't work. But if I did like you told me and added the sub folders name to the code like this: /multi/gallery_964/$1.webp it worked! I guess it will "solve itself" when I'm uploading everything to the root. Even though it's not as clean as one might have hoped. Still don't quite understand why it wont work on sub folders. I really, really appreciate your time and energy spend on this! Can you please leave an answer? Thank you so much.

Probably due to the leading slash in the substitution URL, /gallery_964/$1.webp - try and make that gallery_964/$1.webp instead. Then it should be taken as relative to the directory in which the .htaccess resides.
